# CakePHP, a "settings" page that links to other models. Does it need to be a model itself? , MySQL issues as Result

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP.

I want to have a 'settings' page that links to other models.  i.e. "groups" and "accounts".

I created a model/and controller for "Settings" as that is what I figured I had to do.  Is this a correct assumption?

Now in the 'settings' page, I want to display the MySQL count of "groups" (want to do other things also, but quickly realizing I'm missing something).

in other words, I want to echo the count of [Group Model] in the database in the [Settings Model]

When I try to do that though, CakePHP freaks out and says that there is no table for "Settings" ... and I don't want there to be one.

Whenever I have issues 95% of times you guys show up in google w/answer, but had trouble finding/and wording this one.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to have a Settings model if you don't have a DDBB table or other datasource associated with it. Plus, model names are by convention singular, so it should be Setting.

You made the SettingsController and a view to show some mixed info about your app, which is ok, but you don't need the Setting model. What you need to do is tell Cake you'll use the Group model in this controller, by doing

```
public $uses = array('Group');
```

In most basic tutorials you might not see this since Cake automagically wires up related controllers and models, like GroupsController and Group model.

Now that your SettingsController has the Group model available, you can do:

```
$this->Group->find('count');
```

to find what you need.
You'll probably need to reference more models in SettingsController, like Account.

Comment: thank you so much for answering my question.  I am also new to PHP, have tried to "learn" many times, but found recently it is best to just jump in and try to accomplish what I want to do.  Doesn't seem so "slow" that way.  Really starting to learn a lot since deciding to use CakePHP.  appreciate your answer--works perfectly.  I had "assumed" that Controllers needed models and vis versa.  Starting to make more sense now..